# How does BindingSource determine the data type of the bound data structure?

Tags: vb.net, binding

I'm working with a WinForms app that uses databinding.  I am binding textboxes to a collection of Audit objects that come from an external DLL.

I changed the data type on the PolicyNumber property from Integer to String.  Now, when I put anything other that numeric data into the textbox bound to that property, I get this error: "Conversion from string "3671129ABC" to type 'Double' is not valid."

My question is, where is the BindingSource inferring the type Double from?  My property used to be an Integer, and now it is a String.  I am stumped.  I can post code if it will help.  Thanks

Comment: You'll need to post the code that is setting up the binding

Comment: You should also look at the stack trace of the exception. It's there for a reason.